# How to serve static content over https from a storage bucket with a load balancer with a let's encrypt certificate?

Tags: https, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing, lets-encrypt, certbot

Currently I'm serving the build of a React App (bunch of static files) from a storage bucket so that by using a CNAME redirect in the DNS, the contents load on a domain. But that only works for HTTP ([according to this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https)), and we need HTTPS.

In that same link they tell you to setup a load balancer but that requires a certificate and I don't see a way to set this up with a let's encrypt certificate since I'm not using an vm instance or anything.

I already know that I have to setup an A record to point to the load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out I can create the certificate with a txt dns record for the challenge with: `certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns`. For Public key upload `cert.pem`, for the Certificate chain `chain.pem` and the priviate key is obvious.

The last issue I have may be related to dns cache, if I load the site on firefox (by just typing the domain) it goes directly to the https version, but it chrome it show a google 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on having a Let's Encrypt certificate here's an alternative solution using Cloudflare CDN: [GCS Site over HTTPS](https://geekflare.com/gcs-site-over-https/) (free)